# get div nested in div element using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

For following HTML, I want to parse it and get following result using Nokogiri.

```
event_name = "folk concert 2"   
event_link = "http://www.douban.com/event/12761580/"    
event_date = "20th,11,2010"
```

I know  `doc.xpath('//div[@class="nof clearfix"]')` could get each `div` element, but how should I proceed to get each attribution like `event_name`, and especially the `date`?

HTML

```
 <div class="nof clearfix">        
          <h2><a href="http://www.douban.com/event/12761580/">folk concert 2</a> <span class="pl2">    </span></h2>
            <div class="pl intro">
              Date：25th,11,2010<br/>
            </div>
 </div>
 <div class="nof clearfix">        
          <h2><a href="http://www.douban.com/event/12761581/">folk concert </a> <span class="pl2">    </span></h2>
            <div class="pl intro">
              Date：10th,11,2010<br/>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know xpaths, I prefer to use css selectors, they make more sense to me. [This tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) might be useful for you.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

Event = Struct.new :name , :link , :date

doc = Nokogiri::HTML DATA

events = doc.css("div.nof.clearfix").map do |eventnode|
  name = eventnode.at_css("h2 a").text.strip
  link = eventnode.at_css("h2 a")['href']
  date = eventnode.at_css("div.pl.intro").text.strip
  Event.new name , link , date
end

pp events


__END__
<div class="nof clearfix">        
         <h2><a href="http://www.douban.com/event/12761580/">folk concert 2</a> <span class="pl2">    </span></h2>
           <div class="pl intro">
             Date: 25th,11,2010<br/>
           </div>
</div>
<div class="nof clearfix">        
         <h2><a href="http://www.douban.com/event/12761581/">folk concert </a> <span class="pl2">    </span></h2>
           <div class="pl intro">
             Date: 10th,11,2010<br/>
           </div>
</div>
```

This outputs:

```
[#<struct Event
  name="folk concert 2",
  link="http://www.douban.com/event/12761580/",
  date="Date: 25th,11,2010">,
 #<struct Event
  name="folk concert",
  link="http://www.douban.com/event/12761581/",
  date="Date: 10th,11,2010">]
```